# how to build mongodb-cxx-driver in win

Tags: windows, mongodb, bson

I followed instruction on https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/, but I blocked at **STEP4**, it says:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:135 (generate_export_header):
Unknown CMake command "generate_export_header".

I found this command exists for a long time. I tried cmake3.7rc1 and rc3, but error all the time.
How can I build `bsoncxx`?

Answer (score 0):

just go to that CMakeLists.txt line 134 and add a new line with following code

```
include(GenerateExportHeader)
```

maybe it was included by some dependency in older versions